# Macbook Pro lags when dual screen is connected

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware, high-sierra, dual-screen

My mac acts weird sometimes when I connect it to two of my 1080p screens. The computer will become extremely lagging to the point where it becomes unusable. Things will recover once I unplug either one screen or both screens. (My MBP's screen is closed, power plugged in.)

I didn't have these issues before, therefore my guess is that there is no hardware compatibility issue. However, I think that my gfx should also be adequate to support two 1080p screens.

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening?

Specs:
Macbook Pro, 15 inch (Mid 2014)
2.5 GHz Intel Core i7
16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2 GB

** I have been monitoring my RAM and CPU usage through Activity Monitor when these lag moments happen and they were barely utilised.

** Also ran an Apple Hardware Test but no issues were found.

Comment: Sounds like a GPU issue.

Comment: Same sentiments, is the card dying? Anyway to test it?

Answer (score 1):

Try a different HDMI cable. Not all HDMI cables work well with Macs. Make sure that you get one of a decent quality, those are usually better.

Comment: Tried this but didn't work though... Fan speed increases, lags as usual. I am suspecting a sensor issue.

Comment: Hmm, possibly. What are the monitors?

Comment: It's a small 22-inch samsung and 23 inch dell monitor. I do not have the model numbers on hand.

Comment: We will need those model numbers for support purposes. Take your time with it, but once you get them, let us know.